# Disabling VT100 emulation in Mac Terminal

Tags: terminal

I installed Gimp, Inkscape, and XQuartz on my Mac yesterday.

Today I get an error when I try to use `resize` in the Terminal:

```
$ resize 50 120
resize: Can't set window size under VT100 emulation
```

I did not intentionally enable VT100 emulation (I'm not even sure exactly what that means).  I suspect it is a side effect of installing Gimp, Inkscape, or XQuartz.

I use the basic/default Terminal profile with no customizations other than switching to `/bin/zsh` as the default shell.  I'm using Mac 10.14.5.

How can I turn off or disable VT100 emulation?

(I previously asked this in [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/365157/69638).  After thinking about it more, I'm not sure this is Mac-specific and so that may not have been the best site for this question.)

Edit:

`resize` is not a default command (see comment below).

```
$ which resize
/opt/X11/bin/resize
```

Comment: What command is `resize`? It's not installed on my Mac.

Comment: It is at `/opt/X11/bin/resize`.  I have had that for so long that I forgot it wasn't there by default...

Comment: Oh shoot - I see what happened.  I now have two resize commands on my path ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I was in VT100 emulation mode in the first place.  One of those applications added another program called `resize` to my path.  I was attempting to call a program called resize that I created based on [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/47841/69638).  But now that I have resize from X11, I can follow [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/52054/69638).